# svg-sprite-loader outputPath breaks svgo

Tags: svgo, svg-sprite-loader

My svgo-loader is working fine, until I add an outputPath to my svg-sprite-loader.  At which point the svgo-loader no longer finds the file.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to remove outputPath, and instead alter the spriteFilename to start with the folder like this

```
spriteFilename: `static/icons.${time}.svg`,
```